# firebase cloud messaging execution failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\sankar\Desktop\Firebase Notifications\FireBaseApp\app\google-services.json

Comment: _File google-services.json is missing_

Answer (score 1):

You need to download configuration file from developer portal. And put it into app level project directory.

- For that Visit https://developers.google.com/mobile/add
- You need to download ***google-service.json*** file from
- Copy that file and paste it Into
- *YourApplicationFolder/app* Directory